# How to ensure that there are no duplicates when getting data asynchronously from List without sacrificing performance?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I am developing a website with a background webscraping service. Initially, the service was synchronous and it took approximately 24 hours to scrape 186,000 news articles. Subsequently, I rewrote the service asynchronously to improve its performance. However, upon scraping the data, I discovered that out of 30 news articles saved, only five were unique while the rest were duplicates.

Although I ensured that the code was logically sound, the bug persisted. I explored various possibilities and implemented a `semaphore` to lock the list of URLs in each task, which resolved the issue. However, after running a calculation, I discovered that it would still take about 23.5 hours to scrape all 186,000 news articles. This is far from the desired significant improvement.

Now, I am seeking help on how to avoid using a `semaphore` while also eliminating the above mentioned bug.

Here is the method that the bug occurs in:

```
private async Task<List<News>> GetTheNewsDataAsync(HtmlWeb web, HtmlDocument doc,
    List<string> links)
{
  var news = new List<News>();
  var baseUrl = "https://www.dnes.bg";

  var date = "";
  var dateParsed = new DateTime(1000, 1, 1, 12, 30, 0);
  var imageSrc = "";

  var title = "";
  var sterilizedContent = "";
  var link = "";

  var tasks = new List<Task<News?>>();

  for (int i = 0; i < links.Count; i++) {
    var index = i;
    tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () => {
      link = links[index];
      doc = await web.LoadFromWebAsync(baseUrl + link);

      var titleElement = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//h1[@class='title']");
      if (titleElement != null) {
        title = titleElement.InnerText;
      }

      if (!await CheckIfNewsExistsAsync(title) && title != "") {
        var contentElement = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p");
        if (contentElement != null) {
          sterilizedContent = SterilizeTheNews(contentElement);
        }

        var dateElement = doc.DocumentNode
            .SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='art_author']");

        if (dateElement != null) {

          if (dateElement.InnerText.StartsWith("Обновена")) {
            var pipeIndex = dateElement.InnerText.IndexOf('|');
            date = dateElement.InnerText.Substring("Обновена: ".Length,
                pipeIndex - "Обновена: ".Length).Trim();
          } else {
            date = dateElement.InnerText.Split(',')[0];
          }

          try {
            if (date.Contains("мар")) {
              date = date.Replace("мар", "март");
            }

            dateParsed = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "d MMM yyyy HH:mm",
                new CultureInfo("bg-BG"));
          } catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine($"Exception parsing the date! {e.Message}");
            dateParsed = new DateTime(1000, 1, 1, 12, 30, 0);
          }
        }

        var imageElement = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(
            "//div[@id='article_text']//img");
        if (imageElement != null) {
          imageSrc = imageElement.Attributes["src"].Value;
        } else {
          imageSrc = "https://digitalfinger.id/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/" +
              "no-image-available-icon-6.png";
        }

        var currentNews = new News {
          Title = title,
            Content = sterilizedContent,
            Date = dateParsed,
            ImageUrl = imageSrc
        };

        return currentNews;
      }
      return null;
    }));
  }

  var result = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

  foreach(var item in result) {
    if (item != null) {
      news.Add(item);
    }
  }
  return news;
}
```

Comment: What .NET platform are you targeting? .NET 7?

Answer (score 0):

These variables:

```
var date = "";
var dateParsed = new DateTime(1000, 1, 1, 12, 30, 0);
var imageSrc = "";

var title = "";
var sterilizedContent = "";
var link = "";
```

...should not be shared among all asynchronous operations. Each operation should have its own state. Just move the declaration of these variables inside the `Task.Run` delegate, and the bug should be fixed.

Bonus advice: avoid initializing your variables with dummy values, that are going to be replaced with real values, because the dummy values may end up in the final results. Declare them without a value:

```
string date;
DateTime dateParsed;
string imageSrc;

string title;
string sterilizedContent;
string link;
```

...or even better declare and initialize them with their real value in one step.